# Errno 113 No route to host for Python MQTT Client

Tags: python, python-2.7, mqtt

I have an MQTT server running on 192.168.11.11, For testing i tried to run MQTT client from same server and i got following error

```
[Errno 113] No route to host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt-client.py", line 45, in <module>
    client.connect("192.168.11.11", 30083, 60)  # Connect to (broker, port, keepalive-time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 113] No route to host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt-client.py", line 45, in <module>
    client.connect("192.168.11.11", 30083, 60)  # Connect to (broker, port, keepalive-time)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 839, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 962, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

I did telnet from same broker machine

```
# telnet 192.168.11.11 30083
Trying 192.168.11.11...
Connected to 192.168.11.11.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Check netstat

```
netstat -tulnp | grep 30083
tcp        1      0 0.0.0.0:30083           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15815/kube-proxy
```

But when i changed the code like below and it works

From:

```
client.connect("192.168.11.11", 30083, 60)
```

To:

```
client.connect("0.0.0.0", 30083, 60)
```

Can anyone explain what could be the reason of it?

**EDIT1:**

***Working Code***

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))  
    client.subscribe("app/status")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    logger.info("Disconnected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  
    print("Message received-> " + msg.topic )

try:
    log_setup()
    client = mqtt.Client("amq_comm_test")
    client.enable_logger(logger)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message  
    client.connect("0.0.0.0", 30083, 60)  
    client.loop_forever()  
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # handle Ctrl-C
    logging.warn("Cancelled by user")
except Exception as ex:
    logging.exception("Unhandled error\n{}".format(ex))
    raise
finally:
    logging.shutdown()
```

***Not Working Code***
If i run this code from other machine, it works fine. it only create issue when ActiveMQ and this code run on same server

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))  
    client.subscribe("app/status")


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    logger.info("Disconnected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  
    print("Message received-> " + msg.topic )

try:
    log_setup()
    client = mqtt.Client("amq_comm_test")
    client.enable_logger(logger)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message  
    client.connect("192.168.11.11", 30083, 60)  
    client.loop_forever()  
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.warn("Cancelled by user")
except Exception as ex:
    logging.exception("Unhandled error\n{}".format(ex))
    raise
finally:
    logging.shutdown()
```

Comment: OK, `0.0.0.0` is still meaningless for a destination address, you should try with `127.0.0.1`. But the `No route to host error` for a local IP address may imply your routing table is messed up. Did you run `telnet` on the same machine as the broke or else where?

Comment: It works with 127.0.0.1 too, I run telnet from same machine and it works.